# How to fix API not returning data

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to read in weather data and display it on my home.html
I feel like I've done everything correctly and do not understand what the problem is... Hope one of you can point me in the right direction! thanks for your time.

I am attempting to read json data from a url and output it to screen but I am getting no output whatsoever... These code snippets clearly illustrate what I'm trying to do

in my weather.ts provider I have:

```
 getWeather():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=3a1385634ea148c0b5b175621192204%20&q=52.970490%20-9.419951');
  }
}
```

---

### in my home.html I have:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let w of weather">
          <h2>{{w.condition.text}}</h2>
          <ion-img height='200' width='150' src="{{w.condition.icon}}"></ion-img>
    </ion-item>
```

---

### and i have the following code in my home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  weather:any = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private weatherProvider:WeatherProvider) {

  }
    ionWeatherViewDidLoad(){
      this.weatherProvider.getWeather().subscribe((data)=>{
          this.weather = data.current;
          console.log(this.weather);
      });
    }
  }
```

I expect to see the output in the form of text which states the current weather and also an image which also indicates the weather status... I believe the problem lies with the json file not being read properly by my app... Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Also, here's a link which shows what the json file im attempting to parse looks like https://gyazo.com/12dd0045c522c4e98bc8e8354e60b7a4

Answer (score 0):

**service ts**

```
getWeather(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=3a1385634ea148c0b5b175621192204%20&q=52.970490%20-9.419951").pipe(res => {
      return res;
    });
  }
```

**your ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {

    const weather = this.weatherProvider.getWeather();
    weather.subscribe(
    subscribe(
          (Response  => {
                           this.cDetail = Response;
                           console.log("apI", this.cDetail)
                         })
                         // success

          .catch(error => { console.log(error) }); // fail

 });
```

I think it will work